# Не работает vue3 и переменные scss

Tags: javascript, sass, scss, vue-cli, vue3

В глобальном файле `VUE3` проекта прописываю `SCSS` переменную.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Далее в одном из модулей пытаюсь ее использовать:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Получаю ошибку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                                                  17:57:46

 error  in ./src/components/headerNav.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=14455714&lang=scss&scoped=true

Syntax Error: SassError: Undefined variable.
  ╷
6 │   background-color: $--color-second;
  │                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  E:\Progi3\vue3-perfect-goods\src\components\headerNav.vue 6:21  root stylesheet


 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--9-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader
/src??ref--9-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--1-1!./src/components/
headerNav.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=14455714&lang=scss&scoped=true 4:14-455 15:3-20:5 16:22-463
 @ ./src/components/headerNav.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=14455714&lang=scss&scoped=true
 @ ./src/components/headerNav.vue
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--15-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--15-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-l
oader-v16/dist??ref--1-1!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts
 @ ./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts
 @ ./src/views/Home.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.0.102:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.ts
```

Вопрос:
Почему это происходит и как необходимо реализовать задачу в разрезе данного стека технологий?
P.S. Сам редактор при этом подхватывает цвет переменной корректно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас наверняка ошибка из-за атрибута `scoped` в тэге `style`, где вы задали переменные. Но, в любом случае, вам стоит вынести их в отдельный файл, например `_variables.scss` и импортировать его в местах, где вам нужны эти переменные. Не стоит убирать `scoped`, вам потом сложно будет ориентироваться в стилях и могут возникать проблемы из-за невнимательности, из-за чего вы потеряете время на отладке. Лучше вынесите в файл.   https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html

Comment: К стати scoped если убрать - ошибка не исчезает.
А где лучше всего разместить файл с пресетом scss, если проект выглядит следующим образом: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5ar7.jpg ?

Comment: @MikeKharkov обычно всегда все файлы стилей в папке styles хранят